# Deep XPATH accessing a temp. tree

Tags: xml, xpath, xslt-2.0

I have this variable `$toc`, neatly containing a temp. tree:

```
<epub:nav hidden="hidden" epub:type="toc" id="toc">
    <h2 id="inhoud1">Inhoud</h2>
    <ol>
       <li>
          <a id="idh1x6x4" href="02-Vord.xhtml#idh1x6x4">Voodoo</a>
       </li>
       <li> 
etc.
```

doing `<xsl:sequence select="$toc"/>` outputs the tree as advertised.

However, I cannot XPATH-access anything deeper in the tree like with

```
<xsl:sequence select="$toc//epub:nav/ol/li/a
```

It just outputs nothing at all.
Looking at the variable in XMLSpy shows me that `$toc` is filled as should be:

```
toc  document
  *  document
     epub:nav  element
       hidden   attribute
       epub:type  attribute 
       id         attribute
     h2 element
     ol element

etc.
```

How can I realize the XPATH-access of the `ol`, e.g.?

Comment: Did you register that `epub` prefix in your XSLT file? Try selecting it with the local name: `$toc//*[local-name()='nav']/ol/li/a`

Comment: Yes, it's in <xsl:stylesheet  and no, local-name does not help

Comment: Is there a *default* namespace in your source in some ancestor of those unprefixed tags (ex: `xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"`)? If there is you will either have to declare a prefix for them in the stylesheet or use the `xpath-default-namespace=""` attribute in the tags that select or match using XPath.

Comment: The problem you are describing in your question does not occur with the data you provided. See http://xsltransform.net/948Fn5r. You need to include more details about your problem.

Comment: I see. However, I cannot show the real thing on that site. I access the source indirectly, via an index file which has it's own default custom namespace (prefix=lat). Obviously, my simplification goes too far. It must have something to do with namespaces, as you suggested. Thanks so far.

Comment: Erik, the stylesheet that creates the temporary tree, does it perhaps have some `xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"` declaration on the root element or at least on an ancestor of the `xsl:variable` element? Try to use `<xsl:variable name="toc" xmlns=""><epub:nav hidden="hidden" epub:type="toc" id="toc">..</epub:nav>`. Or alternatively check whether you use `xpath-default-namespace` somewhere in the stylesheet, that way your path might also have a different meaning than you want.

Comment: I found the solution. It was indeed a namespace issue in variable toc and in an other template I use to generate toc. It's not yet clear to me why. I find namespaces a surprisingly difficult subject, in XSLT 2.0. f.i. a variable is in a namespace, but in what namespace are elements IN that variable? Needs more studying. Anyway, thanks for thinking with me.

Answer (score 0):

If i remember you should define which li tag to follow.

I am not sure if the default action is to get the first found tag. 
Try defining which "li" to parse using the following

```
<xsl:sequence select="$toc//epub:nav/ol/li[1]/a
```

Comment: No, that is not the solution.